# Situation of deletion up to come

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

I'm quite new to Stack Overflow, and whatever the quality (high or low) of the question, I noticed frequent deletions of questions once a satisfying answer is given (not only in threads I've been involved in).

Personally, it happened I've answered questions of new
contributors, and the question is either deleted or the asker never accepts the answer and never posts again... a profile per question?

Recently I commented on a question (not from a new contributor) and a dialogue with the submitter, in the comments part, began. The asker edited his question several times with my comments and finally asked me if
he could delete the question: correct code in the question has no sense!

So I feel some frustration with this because sometimes help I gave is simply deleted!

So how can I recognize this situation before it happens?

Comment: Be selective about which questions to answer. Often the risk is greater of self-deletion if it is a new user. Also, the risk is also often greater if the question quality is low and it has been down-voted, or if it is a request to help complete homework (to eliminate evidence of academic cheating). This is not hard and fast, and I'm certainly not recommending that you NOT answer new-user's questions, just that you might wish to be selective based on question quality.

Comment: Besides the Question itself, I started to look for the "Informed" badge. If there isn't any badges at all, they don't have it. If there are some, it may be "Editor" and others, so I often look at their profile. It only takes 5 minutes or less to read everything in the tour.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thank you! "Custom filter" feature does not provide any filter like "No downvote" or "Min. Upvote" or even "Min. reputation". I guess with this kind of feature... new (and real?) contributors will never had an answer...

Comment: @Scratte thanks for the advice.

Comment: Homework vamp burner accounts are common and grossly selfish, insulting and disrespectful but, since only comments can be hostile, toxic and unwelcoming, nothing can be done.

Comment: You can search for total score, though. Like this one [score:0..](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=score%3A0..) When you click on the top search field, there's the most common information and a link to [Search help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching)

Comment: @Martin James: You could poison their wells (I am not sure if that is the right idiom) by providing incorrect answers in a way that would be obvious to someone paying attention, but not to minimum-effort users.

Comment: @PeterMortensen - Shouldn’t we just close the question of its quality is low?

Comment: @SecurityHound quality of the question and being on-topic are not the same thing. Generally "do my homework" question are not showing effort (low quality) and too broad (roughly retyping the textbook up to that assignment) at the same time. Not showing effort by itself *is not* the reason to close the question. "How to search for sub-string ignoring case in lang-Dart" is perfectly valid question even with 0 effort (likely duplicate, but at some point one for language needs to be answered).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - If these extremely low quality and broad questions exist, why are they not being deleted, and why isn’t a question that was researched worthy of being deleted?

Comment: @david some reasons for deletion are given [in this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that). You may find the info useful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TL;DR: Skip anything you are not enjoying *to do*.

It sounds like you had reasonable *dialog* with an author that lead to deletion of off-topic question. First of all this is positive contribution to the site - ideally there would be no visible off-topic/unclear questions and it had to be done one question at a time. Secondly it is quite rare to actually get feedback from to comments, especially positive one - so treat it as water cooler talk and be happy with having interaction with a person.

You should not feel pressed to act on an every question you see - [There is no shame in using "Skip"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252195/there-is-no-shame-in-using-skip) (this is mostly for "edit" reviews but the concept applies across all actions on the site). Only get engaged when you know that you get some enjoyment out of doing it. If commenting that may get question deleted (i.e. "this is typo - missed `;` on line 3") is not your thing *right now* just skip the post. It is far better for you and the site if you contribute on a single question a day and stay happy to do so for years vs. posting on 20 questions get pissed off and never come back. Unlike asking questions (you really can't skip that and still get an answer) all other actions on a site are optional and there are enough of people with different interests to field most of varying duties.

If your personal reason to participate on the site is to have a visible lasting contributions (vs. just showing off what you know or whatever other reasons people have) than you need to pay attention to what you answering and actually post an *answer* (not a comment). One important thing you need to understand that comments are *by design* not a lasting contribution (temporary, can be deleted any time) and comments are *not answers* for the site's purposes (a question with an answer in comments is *not answered* - you just gave someone else chance to easily provide an answer).

One strategy is to scan for the question that you can provide good *answer* to and that are not clear duplicates at the same time. The one drawback of this strategy is significant competition for such already answerable questions but you may find time slot where competition is less.

"Adopt a question" strategy - you found a question that is so-so or on a fence with "too broad", but there is a part you have solid non-duplicate answer to. This is easier when you have full editing rights as narrowing down body of the post (or even worse adding MCVE) usually would be significant change. Editing title to make it clear is likely less controversial and can get approved. Risk here is by providing answer before getting question in shape you risk "this is not answering the question" feedback (including downvotes). Upside is edits/answers push question to "active" list and it get some extra chance for exposure.